# Improve linearity by increasing P1dB by increasing Vds

Tags: compression

So I am using MRF6V2150N as power stage and I was using VDS 28V and increased it to 34V.  I see that the linearity increased since the P1dB shifted upwards. And this also improved (lowered) the IMD3 cause the ACPR also got better.  I want to know if this is true, normal and make sense.  And if so, is there a reference that I can find to back it all up for a report?

THANKS!

Comment: Both it is true and common in general, However if drain load is a transformer or coil, 34V it is too much

Comment: its gonna go to a next stage with 50 Ohm.